# Ideal way of indenting things left and right on the same "line"?

Tags: css, html

So I have two things in a header, namely an image in a h1 and a nav. Here's a simplified version of the HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1><img src="../img/logo.png"></a></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>blahblah</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I want to make the h1 element go to the left and the nav go to the right. I simply gave the header a width and absolutely positioned both h1 and nav like so:

```
header {height: 120px;}
h1 {position:absolute; left: 0;top:0;}
nav {position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
```

It works, but I find it somewhat inelegant. Is there any other nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to just float them left and right without the positioning.

```
header {
   height: 120px;
}
h1 {
   float: left;
}
nav {
   float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

usually you just `float` the elements in their respective corners, such as

```
header { overflow:auto; }
header h1 { float: left; }
header nav { float: right; }
```

`overflow` is used in order for header to retains a height around the elements, but it can be removed in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Float property of CSS allows you to float the element to right or left but if you are looking to indent the element then you may need to use

```
text-indent: 10px;
```

you may add this in a class and add this class to elements wherever you need the Indentation

Comment: OffCourse 10 px is an arbitrary value and you may add any value.